# Keep max value until ID and condition change in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this ([link to csv](https://pastebin.com/embed_js/3tKLJ5Yv))

```
id       time        value   approved
  1       0:00        10       false
  1       0:01        20       true
  1       0:02        30       true
  1       0:03        20       true
  1       0:04        40       false
  1       0:05        35       false
  1       0:06        60       false
  2       0:07        20       true
  2       0:08        30       true
  2       0:09        50       false
  2       0:10        45       false
  2       0:11        70       false
  2       0:12        62       false
```

and I want to create two more columns that will keep the max approved values with a tolerance of 2 secs and the time of the respective max values. So I want it to look like this

```
id       time        value   approved    max_approved   max_time
  1       0:00        10       false         NaN          NaN
  1       0:01        20       true          20           0:01
  1       0:02        30       true          30           0:02
  1       0:03        20       true          30           0:02
  1       0:04        40       false         40           0:04
  1       0:05        35       false         40           0:04
  1       0:06        60       false         40           0:04
  2       0:07        20       true          20           0:07
  2       0:08        30       true          30           0:08
  2       0:09        50       false         50           0:09
  2       0:10        45       false         50           0:09
  2       0:11        70       false         50           0:09
```

How can I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of research I managed to do it this way:

```
canBeTop = (df['approved'].rolling(window = 3, min_periods=1).max() == True)
df['max_approved'] = df.groupby(['id', canBeTop])['value'].transform('cummax').where(canBeTop).ffill()
df['max_time'] = df.where((canBeTop == True) & (df['value'] == df['max_approved']))['time']
df['max_time'] = df.groupby('id', group_keys=False)['max_time'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill())
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic or output is not fully clear, but if I guess correctly, you can try:

```
df['td'] = pd.to_timedelta('0:'+df['time'])

df[['max_approved', 'max_time']] = (df
   .assign(value=df['value'].where(df['approved']),
           last_time=lambda d: d['td'].dt.total_seconds().where(df['approved']),
          )
   .set_index('td').groupby('id')[['value', 'last_time']]
   .apply(lambda s: s.rolling('2s').max().ffill())
   .to_numpy()
)
```

output:

```
    id  time  value  approved              td  max_approved  max_time
0    1  0:00     10     False 0 days 00:00:00           NaN       NaN
1    1  0:01     20      True 0 days 00:00:01          20.0       1.0
2    1  0:02     30      True 0 days 00:00:02          30.0       2.0
3    1  0:03     20      True 0 days 00:00:03          30.0       3.0
4    1  0:04     40     False 0 days 00:00:04          20.0       3.0
5    1  0:05     35     False 0 days 00:00:05          20.0       3.0
6    1  0:06     60     False 0 days 00:00:06          20.0       3.0
7    2  0:07     20      True 0 days 00:00:07          20.0       7.0
8    2  0:08     30      True 0 days 00:00:08          30.0       8.0
9    2  0:09     50     False 0 days 00:00:09          30.0       8.0
10   2  0:10     45     False 0 days 00:00:10          30.0       8.0
11   2  0:11     70     False 0 days 00:00:11          30.0       8.0
12   2  0:12     62     False 0 days 00:00:12          30.0       8.0
```

Comment: I think you missed the part where you computed the helper `td`, right? Can you please add it? Thanks

Comment: much appreciated, this solution works perfectly! I'm pretty new to pandas, could you comment on the solution that @tturbo provided? From what I know using `iterrows()` should be avoided if we can, so your solution is better, right?

Comment: Yes it's slow. In my opinion use of `iterrows` should be restricted to very small datasets when you have no other choice. I use it sometimes for plotting or generation of small reports, almost never for computing data. Other than that I cannot comment on tturbo's solution as it seems incomplete.

Comment: Actually I just realized that the solution does not fit my criteria, possibly I didn't explain it clearly. On the `max_time`, I want to keep the time of the `max_approved` value, so on the row #3 it should have been 2.0, instead of updating to 3.0. And since I can still update the max_approved value 2s after approved turned false, at row #4 it should update `max_approved` to 40 and `max_time` to 4.0. Can you update your answer to match this criteria too? Thanks

Comment: Hey Mozway, sorry to bother you with this again but I still didn't figure out how to do it, so your help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use [iterrows](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to do so

```py
max_value = 0
for index, row_data in df.iterrows():
  # your logic, e.g.
  if row_data.approved and row_data.value > max_value:
    max_value = row_data.value
  df['max_approved'].iloc(index) = max_value
  ...
```

Does this help to get started?

If you want a exact solution, please provide code with the DataFrame (so we don't have to parse the data out of your question. Or your code and where your problems are

Comment: I decided to go with mozway's answer since it was more complete and efficient, but thanks your help anyway! :)